# What are the directives that can create their own scope?

Tags: angularjs

Iam beginner at angularjs.I came to know that some built-in directives can create their own scope.I want to know which directives can create their own scope.

Comment: Go through this [Understanding scopes in AngularJS](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#directives)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs) *New AngularJS developers often do not realize that `ng-repeat`, `ng-switch`, `ng-view`, `ng-include` and `ng-if` all create new child scopes, so the problem often shows up when these directives are involved.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all directives can create their own scope called isolated scope.
when you create directives you have three choices:

1- isolated scope

```
scope:{}
```

2-no scope and use parent scope

```
scope:false
```

3-inherit and access parent scope but new properties add to own scope not parent

```
scope:true
```

Comment: See [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - Scopes](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-)